# How to map À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å to A for more efficient search?

Tags: java, android, regex, search

How to map À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å to A for more efficient search?

I am writing an Android application that need to search a set of strings with those symbols on some character.

In order to make search results more powerful, I would like to map À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å to just A. For example, if the user's query is "Test" the following string should matches with query: Tȅst, Tȇst, Teśt, etc.

Is there any possible way of doing this in Android with API level >= 8?

Comment: You could always replace those characters with A using a string replace.

Comment: Or, use a Collator that considers them all to be equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene does this kind of thing.  Take a look at the `org.apache.lucene.analysis.icu.ICUNormalizer2Filter` for an approach to text normalization for search.

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "Your SeÅrchable Text";
String searchMe = text.replaceAll("[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]", "A");
```

I would just replace all of them in a searchable version of the main String. Pretty simple!
If there are multiple cases (such as weird 'E' characters, just do another replaceAll:

```
searchMe = searchMe.replaceAll("[EEEEEE]", "E"); //(note: those are the weird Es in there)
```

Comment: Simple but are you sure you have dealt with all possible cases?

Comment: I'd be surprised if your approach does work for the OP.  Look at the other Answer and the linked Question for other (better) solutions.